# SignalR `AuthorizeHubConnection` Not getting called .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0, signalr-hub

So, I am trying to implement a simple custom authorization implementation using SingalR in .NET 6. **I am not using JWTs**. Rather I am using something like a PAT for authorization.

I have tried the following in my .NET Server Hub application:

`Program.cs` (relevant SignalR code)

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    o.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
});
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
// SingalR Hub
app.MapHub<ServerHub>("/serverhub", options =>
{
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
});
```

My custom Authorization Attribute (`HubAuthorizationAttribute.cs`):

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Hub.API.Authorization
{
    public class HubAuthorizationAttribute : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute
    { 

        public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
        {
            var incomingClientId = request.QueryString.Where(k => k.Key.Equals("clientId")).Select(v => v.Value);
            var user = request.User.Identity.Name;

            return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
        }

        public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside AuthorizeHubMethodInvokation");
            return base.AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(hubIncomingInvokerContext, appliesToMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my `ServerHub.cs` file I added `[HubAuthorization]` above the Hub like this:

```
[HubAuthorization]
public sealed class ServerHub: Hub
{

...Removed for brevity
}
```

Then, my .NET client for SignalR looks like this:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl($"https://localhost:63929/agenthub?clientid={clientId}", options => 
    {
        //options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            // This will set ALL logging to Debug level
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        })
    .Build();

//Signal R Registration
hubConnection.On<bool>("AgentRegistrationStatusReceived", (isReachable) => {
    if (isReachable)
        Console.WriteLine("(+) Agent is registered!!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("(+) Agent wasn't able to be registered!");
});

// SignalR GetState Request from API Server
hubConnection.On<string, Guid>("GetState", async (callbackMethod, requestId) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving GetState request from server");
    bool isAgentAvailable = await LongPollingTest.GetAgentState();

    Console.WriteLine("Sending GetState response to server");

    await hubConnection.InvokeAsync(callbackMethod, requestId, isAgentAvailable);
});

hubConnection.StartAsync().Wait();
```

My overridden `AuthorizeHubConnection` is never called.
Am I missing something fundamental?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're mixing old and new SignalR? 

> My custom Authorization Attribute (HubAuthorizationAttribute.cs):

This pattern no longer exists with ASP.NET Core SignalR.

Comment: here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-authorization-handlers-to-customize-hub-method-authorization) which explains the new way of authorization with signalr.

Comment: @davidfowl Oh my goodness. Thanks for confirming that. I was actually looking at the libraries yesterday and saw that that AuthorizeAttribute was from ASP.NET SignalR, and not .NET Core. I appreacite it!

Comment: @CodingMytra yes, I came across that, and tried to implement, but still get a 403 when the Hub tries to make a connection....
I am trying without JWT, and only want the authorization to happen at connection level, not at invoke levels..

Comment: What are you trying exactly?